# A Deadlock Problem When Dealing with Producer-Consumer Java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, java-threads

I am trying to implement producer and consumer problem in different ways. Hence, I created two consumer and one producer threads. The task is to print even numbers in Consumer1 Thread and odd numbers in Consumer2 Thread. I know that I am using anti-patterns and do everything incorrectly, but it is just an experimentation.

Anyways, whenever I run the program, I do come across with potentially deadlock situations.
I assume this because the program prints nothing to the console.

**Class Info:**

NumbersThread: the class at the top of inheritance three. Provides shared Queue

ProducerThread: randomly generates numbers in range 0 to 49 and pushes them to Queue.

Consumer1Thread: prints even numbers in the Queue

Consumer2Thread: prints odd numbers in the Queue

Here is class-by-class code:

### NumbersThread

```
class NumbersThread extends Thread {
private int capacity = 64;
private final Queue<Integer> numbersQueue;


// field variables, constructors etc.

// peek, poll, and add methods synchronized on numbersQueue

protected final void notifyAllForFull() {
    synchronized (FULL_LOCK) {
        FULL_LOCK.notifyAll();
    }
}

protected final void notifyAllForEmpty() {
    synchronized (EMPTY_LOCK) {
        EMPTY_LOCK.notifyAll();
    }
}

protected final void waitOnEmpty() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (EMPTY_LOCK) {
        EMPTY_LOCK.wait();
    }
}

protected final void waitOnFull() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (FULL_LOCK) {
        FULL_LOCK.wait();
    }
}
```

}

### Producer Thread

```
class ProducerThread extends NumbersThread {

ProducerThread(Queue<Integer> numbersQueue) {
    super(numbersQueue);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    run:
    while (true) {
        while (isFull()) {
            try {
               waitOnFull();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break run;
            }
        }

        var rand = new Random();
        add(rand.nextInt(50));
        notifyAllForEmpty();
    }
}
```

}

### Consumer1 Thread (the same logic with Consumer2)

```
class Consumer1Thread extends NumbersThread {
Consumer1Thread(Queue<Integer> numbersQueue) {
    super(numbersQueue);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    run:
    while (true) {

        while (isEmpty()) {
            try {
                waitOnEmpty();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break run;
            }
        }

        Integer num = peek();

        if (num != null && num % 2 == 0  ) {
            int n = poll();
            notifyAllForFull();
            System.out.println("Consumer 1 (even): " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any helps will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one* problem: Suppose a consumer calls `waitOnEmpty()`. **Q:** After that call returns, is the queue empty or not empty? **A:** You have no way of telling.

The problem is, you have two consumers. If one of them is waiting for the queue to become non-empty, then chances are, both of them are waiting. If the producer puts one number into the queue and then wakes both consumers, then both `waitOnEmpty()` calls will return, but only one of two consumers will be able to remove a number from the queue. The other consumer will find the queue to be empty even though `waitOnEmpty()` returned.

When you use `wait()` and `notify()`, you need to do it like this:

**Consumer**

```java
synchronized (lock) {
    while (conditionIsNotMet()) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    // !! While still in the SAME `synchronized` block!!
    doThingThatRequiresConditionToBeMet();
}
```

**Producer**

```java
synchronized (lock)  {
    doThingThatMeetsCondition();
    // !! While still in the SAME `synchronized` block!!
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

The important part is, the consumer does not unlock the lock after testing the condition and before doing whatever requires the condition to be true. Staying in that same `synchronized` block is what keeps other threads (especially, other consumers) from changing whether or not the condition still *is* true after the consumer has tested it.

---

* Maybe not the only problem. I haven't thoroughly reviewed your code.